# Call reverse method

Tags: java

Problem: I hope to call reve method, the result should be "edcba". But the real result is "abcde". The reve method does not work well. Any suggestion to solve it ?  Thanks a lot

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class Reverse {


    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException

    {
          System.out.println(reve("abcde"));    
    }


    // to reverse a string
    public static String reve(String sentence) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sentence.length() + 1);
        String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
        for (int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            sb.append(words[i]).append(' ');
        }
        sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);  // Strip trailing space
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you called the reve method from your main?)

Comment: what output do you expect from "foo bar"? "rab oof" or "oof rab"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` won't help you here as there are no space in between characters

```
 String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
```

Use

```
 char[] words = sentence.toCharArray();
```

So that you can get characters from `String` and than use loop to reverse the `String` as I think you are doing that properly but do that for character array instead.

Or you can Use `charAt(int i)` method as well.

```
for (i = sentence.length()-1; i >= 0; i--)
      sb.append(sentence.charAt(i));
    return sb.toString();
```

***NOTE:***
Here you can directly Use method `reverse()` of `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`

```
System.out.println(new StringBuilder(stringVar).reverse().toString());
System.out.println(new StringBuffer(stringVar).reverse().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are splitting the string on space. Since `"abcde"` has no spaces, `split` gives you only an array with one element (`"abcde"`) and you append it to the `StringBuilder`.

Since you are already using a `StringBuilder`, you could simply do

```
public static String reve(String sentence) {
    return new StringBuilder(sentence).reverse().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are spliting in *space*. Since the string `"abcde"` doesn't contain any space it will return just one element (the whole string).

One easy solution would be to split in *nothing*, so you get each letter separated:

```
String[] words = sentence.split("");
```

But the most recommended solution would be to convert the string into a `char` array, because in this case, it doesn't make sense to store the characters in a `String` array, since there will only be one character per string:

```
char[] letters = sentence.toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work fine (using char array):

```
public static String reve(String sentence) {

  char[] characters = sentence.toCharArray();
  int i = 0;
  int j = sentence.length()-1;

  while(j > i) {
    char temp = characters[i];
    characters[i] = characters[j];
    characters[j] = temp;
    i++;j--;
  }

  return new String(characters);
}
```